# jQuery - 2 different functions for 2 different submit buttons in one form

Tags: jquery

I have had a search around at other suggestions for what i want to do, but none seems to have what i need.

Basically i have a form with 2 submit buttons, i want one to save the data to the database, which i have done and works perfect ... the second submit button ( preview ) i need to open in a new window, take all the form data and display it on a form while leaving the previous page as it is ... if that makes sense.

I figure i cant do this with PHP as to get the post data it needs to basically reload a page ... i thought there might be a way with jQuery.

Any help?

Comment: You can use GET instead of POST. Or another option would be simply showing dialog box (or something similar) on the same page.

Comment: Does your first submit button reload the page?

Comment: @mellamokb - Yes the first submit button saves teh data to the database and redirects to a thanks page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use jQuery for this unless you're already using it elsewhere in the application.

HTML Markup:

```
<form method="post" action="foo.php" id="myform">
    <button type="submit" name="save_data">Save Data</button>
    <button type="submit" name="preview_data" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').target = '_blank'; return true;">Preview Data</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['preview_data'])) {
    // Clicked Preview
} else if (isset($_POST['save_data'])) {
    // Clicked Save
} else {
    // How'd you get here? Probably not POST
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh awesome, this is what i needed .. and to make the save button appear in the same window, i would use the same code on the save button and then just replace the _blank with _parent ... is that right?

Comment: In the same window would be `_self`, but you could take out the whole "onclick" attribute anyway since _self is the default target for the form.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you need to use script for the 2nd button.

Would look something like this (using jQuery):

```
<button type="button" id="preview_button">preview</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#preview_button').click(function(){
        var pUrl = 'http://server/preview.php?' + $('#form_id').serialize();
        window.open(pUrl);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that ... Ill give it a shot ... how does one get info out of the serialize function though? ... cheers

Comment: The serialize function will return a string, which looks like this:  a=foo&b=bar.  These will just be parameters to the GET.

Comment: @John - This works, but im gathering there is a limit on GET data ... is there anyway to do it using POST?

Comment: No, you can't post through JavaScript that way.  That requires a full form post, which gets trickier.

GET should be fine up through at least 1000 bytes, and you can can always binhex your data if you've got crazy characters in the string.

Comment: Bugger ... ok thanks for that ... just one more thing ,,, instead of using serialize, is there any way i can split the data, as im using code igniter and it doesnt support GET, it needs the url to be setup like /site.com/forminput/response/forminput/response

Comment: You can serialize the data any way you want.  : )

    var pArr = $('#form_id').split('&');
    var pOut = [];
    for (var i=1; i < pArr.length; i+=2)
    {
        pOut.push(pArr[i].split('=')[1]);
    }
    var pUrl = 'http://server/forminput/' + pOut.join('/'); 
    // or whatever works for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Of cours that it's possible with jQuery. All you need to do is to write two onClick functions (to each button). In first function simply call $("form_name").submit() and your data will be submited.

And in the second function open the dialog (you can use this http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), get all data from the form and put it into dialog in the way you need them).
To get all data from your form you can user another jQuery function $("form_name").serialize(). Take look here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your preview button isn't a submit button, but should just be a regular button that you set a new click function for.

In that function you can open the new window with the fields from the form.

If you want the new window to do a round trip to the server, you could use an ajax call as John suggested or perhaps when the 2nd button is clicked set a flag in a hidden field and your server side script can check that flag to determine if it should save the data or generate the preview page.